# How to create two authorized users (Admin, customer) in one login page?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, admin

I have recently created a login page for customer. but now i want to develop admin dashboard before i want to create a login page for admin. how can i manage two authorized users at same login page. Below i attached my codes and mentioned file name also.

routes/users.js

```
 // Passport
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username,password, done){
  Customer.getUserByUsername(username, function(err,user){
   if(err) throw err;
   if(!user){
     return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
   }

   Customer.comparePassword(password,user.password,function(err, isMatch){
     if(err) throw err;
     if(isMatch){
       return done(null, user);
     } else {
          return done(null, false, {message:'Invalid password'});
     }
   });
 });
}));



 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  Customer.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
  done(err, user);
   });
  });


  router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local',{successRedirect:'/home', 
  failureRedirect:'/login',failureFlash: true}),
  function(req,res){
    res.redirect('/home');
  });
```

Below my model schema code.

```
  var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
   type:String
   },
   username: {
   type: String,
   unique: true
   },
   email:{
   type: String
   },
   password:{
   type: String
   },
  confirmpassword : {
  type: String
  }

  });

  var Customer = module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer',UserSchema);
  module.exports.createUser = function(newUser,callback){

  bcrypt.genSalt(10,function(err,salt){
  bcrypt.hash(newUser.password,salt,function(err,hash){
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
  });
  });
  }

  module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback)
  {
  var query = {username: username};
  Customer.findOne(query,callback);
  }

  module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback)
  {
  Customer.findById(id,callback);
  }


  module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, 
 callback) 
 {
 bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
  if(err) throw err;
  callback(null, isMatch);
  console.log(isMatch);
  });
 }
```

Can someone tell me how can i develop two authorized login system at same page. If admin log in then system will redirect to admin dhashboard. Unless user login then it will redirect to user dashboard.

Comment: **You can assign Department or Role in your schema**,
 As per your schema remove confirm password field from mongoose.
Password and confirm password is only for front-end validation

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest approach to achieve this would be to create a flag in the table for roles eg create is_admin key for users who are admin. After than at the time of login, add a check also for the user whether is_admin flag is true or false. If true, then create a middle ware for this and add this middle ware to the routes for the admin.

Comment: Hey can you plz share some example code depends on my code section